# Failed to Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App

Tags: java, spring, maven, vaadin, vaadin22

When im trying to build my application to upload my project to azure I have the next errors and debugging it with "mvn -e -X -Pproduction -DskipTests clean package":

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:22.0.0:build-frontend (default) on project cinema: Could not execute build-frontend goal: Error occured during goal execution: Type [unknown] not presentPlease run Maven with the -e switch (or Gradle with the --stacktrace switch), to learn the full stack trace. org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisherAware: org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware -> [Help 1]


Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not execute build-frontend goal

Caused by: com.vaadin.flow.server.ExecutionFailedException: Error occured during goal execution: Type [unknown] not presentPlease run Maven with the -e switch (or Gradle with the --stacktrace switch), to learn the full stack trace.

Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationEventPublisherAware
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Vaadin project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/1e82b309-3fef-4d97-b376-4d9e20b1dd3e -->
    <groupId>com.cinema.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>cinema</artifactId>
    <name>Project base for Spring Boot and Vaadin Flow</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>22.0.0</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>
                https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/
            </url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>exampledata</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
              <artifactId>h2gis</artifactId>
              <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Configuracion del ORM de spring boot para persistencia -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

this is how my pom.xml looks like, I think im not missing any dependency or anything, have spent all day trying to figure out what's going on here, thanks.

any idea how could I handle those problems?

Edit: this is the repo if u wanna try by yourself.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o6K3DKMu9TdA0QFYqyP4rgWoAChnRNh/view

Comment: How does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: It might be useful to compare your setup with how the deployment is done in this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/cloud-deployment/azure.

Comment: The repo seems to be private

Comment: @TarekOraby i have tried it, and haven't worked.

Comment: i have uploaded it on my drive with the DB. @SimonMartinelli thanks very much.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o6K3DKMu9TdA0QFYqyP4rgWoAChnRNh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is two unnecessary annotations in the `Application` class**

You don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` because your package structure is hierarchical correct. Plus this annotation without defining packages does not make sense. Remove it.

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` is already on `@SpringBootApplication`. Remove this.

**Then there are some issues in the pom.xml.**

You shouldn't override the Spring Boot version like here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can remove all these dependencies because they already come with the starter dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it solved the problem.

Another question not related with the post, I have tried to create several logins with spring security and also with vaaadin, but im always failing at the authentication process, looks like it never compares the values with the DB, any advice? or tutorial that I could follow?

Comment: If you use https://start.vaadin.com you can go to the settings tab and configure security there and see how it's done

Comment: Btw if my answer was helpful and correct please accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. However, I could not simply get rid of the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on my `Application` class as it was needed to configured some packages to scan. But implementing the `AppShellConfigurator` in a separate component (i.e. not in the `Application` class) did the trick for me.

So in my case, the `Application` class ended up looking something like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { ... })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { ... })
...
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer { ... }
```

And the separate `AppShellConfigurator` implementation looked like this:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.AppShellConfigurator;
import com.vaadin.flow.theme.Theme;

@Component
@Theme(MyTheme.THEME_NAME)
public class MyAppShellConfigurator implements AppShellConfigurator { }
```